# Dynamic creation of views and getWidth methods on android

Tags: android, dynamic, view, android-relativelayout

I had problems with getWidth methods on layouts and views so I tried separating creation and placing of views inside parent. At start, activity starts the method loadResources() which gets all favicons from database, creates imageviews for them and in other loop after assigning them to relativeLayout parent tries placing them on screen. But nothing is on screen??

Here's the code:

```
private void loadResources() {

    cursor = managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, projection, selection,
    null, Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS + " DESC");

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        bookmarkCounter = 1;
        ByteArrayInputStream blobImage;

        do{
           bookmark = new ImageView(this);
           bookmark.setId(bookmarkCounter++);
           bookmark.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

           blobImage = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                   cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(BookmarkColumns.FAVICON)));

           bookmark.setImageDrawable(
                   Drawable.createFromStream(blobImage, "" + bookmark.getId()));

           params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                   (int) (40 * scale), (int) (40 * scale));

           params.topMargin = (int) (scale * 20);
           params.leftMargin = (int) (scale * 20);
           relativeLayout.addView(bookmark, params);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        int idOfViewToTheLeft = 1;

        for(int counter = 1; counter < bookmarkCounter; counter++) {

            bookmark = (ImageView) findViewById(counter);

            Log.v("WIDTH", "" + relativeLayout.getWidth());

            if(bookmarkCounter > 1) {
               if(relativeLayout.getWidth() > (bookmark.getLeft() + bookmark.getWidth())) {
                   params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, bookmark.getId() - 1);
               } else {
                   params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, idOfViewToTheLeft);
                   idOfViewToTheLeft = bookmark.getId();
               }
            }

            bookmark.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            bookmark.setLayoutParams(params);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

     }
    }
```

}

Comment: You placed `setcontentview` at the very end of your method, and that only would apply the empty, unbinded layout.main to the screen.

Comment: True, I removed it. Now I only get 1 icon, seems I didn't update position of the view right. How to do that?

Comment: you can't get size or position in onCreate(), they will only work once views are laid out. the point is you're doing layout job in oncreate: you should create your own layout deriving from RelativeLayout, overriding onLayout() and doing there the job.

Comment: Ok thanks, can you reference me to a tutorial please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by working out the math manually with screenwidth and setting the margins of layout params.

Answer (score 1):

if i can understand your question correctly, i guess this is what you need to look at........... use onSizeChange() of your view........ here is an EXTENDED code snippet http://syedrakibalhasan.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-get-width-and-height-dimensions.html